# Requests to all Localhost Ports through Browser return "connection blocked"

Tags: linux, networking, localhost, loopback

I wanted to open page on localhost that used to work before but this time browser showed only (as html `<pre>` tag's content)

```
connection blocked
```

Other Apache pages on other ports are not working as well.

I run Vue.js development server, it didn't work on localhost but worked on other device in local network.

Request to 0.0.0.0:8080 responds for example with

```
read tcp 10.238.4.28:43777: read: connection refused
```

Result of netstat -lntu

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::777                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5002                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5003                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::555                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5004                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::333                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5008                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::888                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::444                  :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60641           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::44579                :::*
```

These ports 777, 888, 5004, 5008 and others I was using in development with localhost.

ifconfig lo (ifconfig of loopback) returns

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 4477  bytes 1476790 (1.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4477  bytes 1476790 (1.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have ufw disabled

The network card is working, xampp installed on windows returned localhost welcome page correctly.

How to restore connection to localhost that used to work before? I don't know even where to search for solution to my problem.

EDIT

curl and wget return html properly but Firefox and Chrome fail and show

```
connection refused
```

Comment: With `netstat -tulpn` it will also show the program name listening on these ports, so you can verify the service you expect is listening on the ports you expect. E.g. if there is some proxy that tries to connect further on but can't then might give back only some limited information (e.g. a devserver?!). Just my 2 cents, hope this helps.

Comment: Netstat -tulpn returns nothing more, program name is empty

Comment: Update it is showing apache correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good possibility that something is messing with your browser.

Open an incognito window and try opening the URL. If it opens up, there could be a software that is blocking these connections. In my case it was a VPN software installed within the browser.

Apart from this, try using Internet Explorer or any other clean browser to open the URL. You could also try looking for some anti-virus or anti-malware software as these could be trying to limit the connection too.

Hope this helps! Thanks!